# What's the point of def some_method(param: int) syntax?

Tags: python, parameters

Specifically the ":int" part...

I assumed it somehow checked the type of the parameter at the time the function is called and perhaps raised an exception in the case of a violation.  But the following run without problems:

```
def some_method(param:str):
    print("blah")

some_method(1)

def some_method(param:int):
    print("blah")

some_method("asdfaslkj")
```

In both cases "blah" is printed - no exception raised.

I'm not sure what the name of the feature is so I wasn't sure what to google.

EDIT: OK, so it's http://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-3107/.  I can see how it'd be useful in frameworks that utilize metadata.  It's not what I assumed it was.  Thanks for the responses!

FOLLOW-UP QUESTION - Any thoughts on whether it's a good idea or bad idea to define my functions as def some_method(param:int) if I really only can handle int inputs - even if, as pep 3107 explains, it's just metadata - no enforcement as I originally assumed?  At least the consumers of the methods will see clearly what I intended.  It's an alternative to documentation.  Think this is good/bad/waste of time?  Granted, good parameter naming (unlike my contrived example) usually makes it clear what types are meant to be passed in.

Comment: [Function annotations](http://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-3107/)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

it's not used for anything much - it's just there for experimentation (you can read them from within python if you want, for example).  they are called "function annotations" and are described [in pep 3107](http://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-3107/).

i wrote a library that builds on it to do things like type checking (and more - for example you can map more easily from JSON to python objects) called [pytyp](http://www.acooke.org/pytyp/) ([more info](http://www.acooke.org/pytyp.pdf)), but it's not very popular... (i should also add that the type checking part of pytyp is not at all efficient - it can be useful for tracking down a bug, but you wouldn't want to use it across an entire program).

[update: i would not recommend using function annotations in general (ie with no particular use in mind, just as docs) because (1) they might eventually get used in a way that you didn't expect and (2) the exact type of things is often not that important in python (more exactly, it's not always clear how best to specify the type of something in a useful way - objects can be quite complex, and often only "parts" are used by any one function, with multiple classes implementing those parts in different ways...).  this is a consequence of [duck typing](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Duck_typing) - see the "more info" link for related discussion on how python's abstract base classes could be used to tackle this...]

Answer (score 3):

Function annotations are what you make of them.

They can be used for documentation:

```
def kinetic_energy(mass: 'in kilograms', velocity: 'in meters per second'):
     ...
```

They can be used for pre-condition checking:

```
def validate(func, locals):
    for var, test in func.__annotations__.items():
        value = locals[var]
        msg = 'Var: {0}\tValue: {1}\tTest: {2.__name__}'.format(var, value, test)
        assert test(value), msg


def is_int(x):
    return isinstance(x, int)

def between(lo, hi):
    def _between(x):
            return lo <= x <= hi
    return _between

def f(x: between(3, 10), y: is_int):
    validate(f, locals())
    print(x, y)


>>> f(0, 31.1)
Traceback (most recent call last):
   ... 
AssertionError: Var: y  Value: 31.1 Test: is_int
```

Also see http://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0362/ for a way to implement type checking.

Answer (score 1):

Not experienced in python, but I assume the point is to annotate/declare the parameter type that the method *expects*.  Whether or not the expected type is rigidly enforced at runtime is beside the point.

For instance, consider:

```
intToHexString(param:int)
```

Although the language may technically allow you to call `intToHexString("Hello")`, it's not semantically meaningful to do so.  Having the `:int` as part of the method declaration helps to reinforce that.

Answer (score 1):

It's basically just used for documentation. When some examines the method signature, they'll see that `param` is labelled as an `int`, which will tell them the author of the method expected them to pass an `int`.

Because Python programmers use duck typing, this doesn't mean you *have* to pass an `int`, but it tells you the code is expecting something "int-like". So you'll probably have to pass something basically "numeric" in nature, that supports arithmetic operations. Depending on the method it may have to be usable as an index, or it may not.

However, because it's syntax and not just a comment, the annotation is visible *to any code that wants to introspect it*. This opens up the possibility of writing a `typecheck` decorator that can enforce strict type checking on arbitrary functions; this allows you to put the type checking logic in one place, and have each method declare which parameters it wants strictly type checked (by attaching a type annotation) with a minimum on syntax, in a way that is visible to client programmers who are browsing method definitions to find out the interface.

Or you could do other things with those annotations. No standardized meaning has yet been developed. *Maybe* if someone comes up with a killer feature that uses them and has huge adoption, then it'll one day become part of the Python language, but I suspect the flexibility of using them however you want will be too useful to ever do that.

Comment: Building on that idea, I wonder if instead of specifiying _int_ you might specify something like _numerical_value_ since it's just metadata anyway.  You would have to define _number_value_ somewhere and one downside (at least in PyCharm) is that _number_value_ doesn't stick out with a bright color the way _int_ does.  However, there may be some setting to make this possible.

Answer (score 1):

You might also use the "-> returnValue" notation to indicate what type the function might return.

```
def mul(a:int, b:int) -> None:
    print(a*b)
```